# Open Office. Counting and summing one column based on criteria from a second column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of letters (A to C), that I would like to count up if they match the corresponding criteria in another column.  For instance, column B has the letters A,B,A,C,C,C in this order .  Column A has the letters A,C,A,C,B,B in this order.  I would like a formula that can be placed at the bottom of column B which will count up only those letters that match in the same row as column A.  In this example, I would like the number 3 to be displayed, as three of the 6 letters match in the corresponding row.

I imagine that there is a fairly simple formula to produce this, but after searching and many failed attempts, I hope someone will me able to help out with this.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A1:A6=B1:B6))
```

Comment: Wonderful.  Thanks for the quick response and help for such a simple question.